# Origen de la expresión "quedarse con el culo torcido"

Tags: expresiones, coloquialismos

En el español europeo tenemos una expresión bastante contundente: *quedarse con el culo torcido*. Según mi propia experiencia y por lo que he podido leer, se usa cuando algo te sorprende hasta el punto de dejarte sin palabras y pensando en lo que acabas de experimentar, incluso a veces con sensación de mal rollo.

Su uso se atestigua [incluso en la prensa](https://www.lavanguardia.com/series/mejores-series/20200718/482365624030/el-colapso-filmin-critica.html):

> La principal candidata a 'serie del verano' te dejará con el culo torcido

En la hemeroteca de la Biblioteca Nacional de España he encontrado casos en artículos de 2008 como muy pronto. Dado que el ejemplar con el artículo más antiguo que usa la expresión es de acceso restringido, lo único que puedo copiar del mismo es lo siguiente:

> *[...] me quedo con el culo torcido, me pregunto cómo pueden haber salido esas cosas de la cabeza de [...].*
>
> **El Correo español (Bilbao).** 8/8/2008, página 120.

En todo caso creo que es suficiente para comprobar el significado que se le da a la expresión. Buscando en Google y filtrando resultados por fecha veo que la expresión es un poco más antigua, encuentro páginas que hablan de *quedarse con el culo torcido* ya a principios de la década de los 2000.

Por experiencia sé que tratar de averiguar el origen de expresiones tan recientes es complicado, dada la cantidad de información existente. Aun así, preguntas:

- ¿Cuánto más antigua es la expresión? ¿Se pueden encontrar casos previos al año 2000 con el mismo significado?
- ¿De dónde viene la expresión? He visto casos cercanos al año 2000 que usan la expresión *culo torcido* con otro sentido que no identifico ("Va a hacer falta un ejército lleno de policías culo torcido a venir a buscarme"), no sé si el origen de la expresión puede venir originado a partir de este o no.

Comment: Me acordé de "quedarse con el poto a dos manos" https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/con_el_culo_en_dos_manos

Comment: Como  intuitivamente te puedes imaginar a alguien que está sentado, y que por la sorpresa gira tan rápido que sus posaderas se resisten al giro por la fricción con el asiento, no tiene nada de raro que se vaya extendiendo una vez alguien lo pone en Internet.  Fijo que lo acuñó algún chistoso  al ver a alguien girarse de golpe en su silla por algún sobresalto, pero vaya usted a saber quién.